# Print all the subsequences of a string using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, subsequence

I have tried a approach of print all the subsequences of a stirng using recursion but not able to implement this how can i print all the subsequences of a string in **lexicographical order**.
INPUT:-
abc
OUTPUT:
a
b
c
ab
ac
bc
abc

I have tried this approach to print all the subsequences of a string:

```
void print(string s,string temp)
{
    if(s.empty()){
        cout<<temp<<endl;
        return;
    }
    print(s.substr(1),temp + s[0]);
    print(s.substr(1),temp);
}
```

Comment: Explain your code thoroughly. What `temp` stands for? What does the print function do?

Comment: Shouldn't `ab` come before `b`, just like it would in a normal dictionary or alphabetical list?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to have is a so called power set. Please read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) about that.

There are som many examples for recursive approaches, that I will not show my onw solution. Maybe best for you would be:

[this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-program-to-generate-power-set/)

And, if you want to have a little bit more background information then please look [here](https://medium.com/outco/how-to-solve-power-set-c8ef7d1382ee)